# ifstream struct read (What's wrong with my code??)

Tags: c++, ifstream

I save struct array as binary. (fIn.write)

and I read it using below code.

```
std::ifstream fIn(LOG_PATH, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
...
IAttackSave_t IAttackSave;
while(fIn.read((char*)&IAttackSave, sizeof(IAttackSave_t)))
{   
        for(uint32 ulIdx = 0; ulIdx < ulCurLogCnt; ++ulIdx)
        {
            LIB_memcpy(Arr_IAttackSave[ulIdx], &IAttackSave, sizeof(IAttackSave_t));
        }
}
```

But, (array) All of element in 'Arr_IAttackSave' has same struct !!!!

What's wrong with my code??

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Well, you are using a loop to copy the currently read value into (presumably) all elements of the array. Not sure why you are doing that. Also this isn't a [mre]

Comment: @UnholySheep I found my fault. Thanks for help.

Comment: Please don't edit the question to remove the problem, because that invalidates the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer loop reads elements one by one. The inner loop overwrites all elements of the array with the same element. After both loops finish, all elements have been overwritten with the element that was read last.

Instead, you need something like this:

```
for(uint32 ulIdx = 0; ulIdx < ulCurLogCnt; ++ulIdx)
{
    if (!fIn.read((char*)&IAttackSave, sizeof(IAttackSave_t))) {
        break;
    }
    LIB_memcpy(Arr_IAttackSave[ulIdx], &IAttackSave, sizeof(IAttackSave_t));
}
```